# does the Node.js driver for MongoDB support functions as selectors?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

does the [Node.js mongoDB](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) driver support [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/) predicates in `remove(…)`/`count(…)` operations? it seems to work for a regular `find(…)`, but i receive unexpected results (false positives) with other operations.

Comment: Yes that's supported.  Can you provide a specific example that's not working as you expect?

Comment: yeah, i'll prepare a test case soon to double-check myself. i could just be blundering on asynchronous programming since i'm not used to it - i just didn't see literal functions in the documentation and couldn't figure out what else might have gone wrong. thank you for the followup, @JohnyHK!